# Why can't bound method access the outside function in a class?

Tags: python, scope

Something really confused me today.
Let's assume `foo.py` :

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        b()
        #c()

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print("b called!")


def c():
    print("c called!")

a=A()

a.a()

print(a.a)
print(type(A.b))
print(type(c))
```

Then when I access function `b` in `a` I will encounter error:`NameError: name 'b' is not defined`.
Can't function `b` be accessed inside method `a`? Both `b` and `c` are functions, only `c` can be accessed inside `a`.Why?

Comment: Try calling `self.b()` instead of `b()` when referring to the function within `A`.

Comment: @CampbellMcDiarmid Maybe you should put that in an actual answer...

Comment: BTW, are you sure you _really_ need a `staticmethod` there? Even though Python provides `staticmethod` they don't get used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `self.b()` instead of `b()` when referring to the *member function* `b` of the class `A`.  Each instance of `A` is a unique object, members and attributes of an instance can be referred to using `self`.

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        self.b()
        c()

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print("b called!")

def c():
    print("c called!")
```

We can refer to `c` without using `self.c()` as it is not a member of `A`.  Member function `b` **does not** take `self` as the first argument, as a `staticmethod` **does not** call to or alter any other members of the object.  Member function `a` **is not** considered a `staticmethod` of `A`, because it calls another member function (`b`) of the instance `self`.

(**Note:** `self` is not a keyword, but a widely used convention).

Comment: Thank you! I still have something troubling me: all of the instances of `A` share the same static method `b` just like Java?

Comment: If so , why should we access the `b()` with `self.b()`? Does this mean static method gets a copy for every instance of `A` and doesn't take the instance itself as the first positional argument?

Comment: All instances of `A` share the same `b`, and other `staticmethod`s.  You can check this by using the `id` builtin.  For example, if you set two instances of `A`, `a1 = A()`, `a2 = A()` and compare the ID of static vs non-static methods `id(a1.a) == id(a2.a)` returns `False` and `id(a1.b) == id(a2.b) == id(A.b)` returns `True`.  From the description of `id` " Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
    simultaneously existing objects.", I assume that each instance refers to the original static method `b`.

Comment: I know python has a rule for searching variables: LEGB. Can we see method as a kind of variable? By the way, in my PC, both `id(a1.a) == id(a2.a)` and `id(a1.b) == id(a2.b)` are `True`. You can have a try.

Comment: I try `print(a1.a)` and `print(a2.a)` They are actually not the same memory address. But `id()` returns the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I got memory address and identification mixed up in my explanation, my apologies.  I guess you could say that it is like a variable.  You can assign a method to a variable and override it like a variable.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning you can call non-static methods two different ways.  Calling `A.a(a1)` would produce the same result as `a1.a()`.  In the first case you are passing in instance `a1` for the `self` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the `b` is the static method of the class `A`, not just a function from the outer scope. It has to be accessible with this syntax:

`A.b()`

Comment: Static methods can be called either on the class (such as `A.b()`) or on an instance (such as `a.b()`). The instance is ignored except for its class.